# Splitting a binary file on binary delimiter?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, binary, grep

I'm working on a shell script to convert MPO stereographic 3D images into standard JPEG images. A MPO file is just two JPEG images, concatenated together.

As such, you can split out the JPEG files by finding the byte offset of the second JPEG's magic number header (0xFFD8FFE1). I've done this manually using hexdump/xxd, grep, head, and tail.

The problem here is grep: what can I use to search a binary directly for a specific magic number, and get back a byte offset? Or should I not use a shell script for this at all? Thanks.

Comment: For the record, these files are produced by a Fujifilm FinePix Real 3D W3 camera.

Comment: Also, it appears that the left-lens image comes first in the MPO file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a much better explanation of MPO file structure (and how to process it correctly) at http://www.davidglover.org/2010/09/using-the-fuji-finepix-real-3d-w3-camera-on-a-mac-or-linuxunix.html

Edit, October 2019:

Since the blog entry now 404s, here is the script that I wrote based on it. I haven't used it in many years.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Script to convert 3D MPO files, as used in the Fuji FinePix series of 3D cameras, into standard JPEG files.
# Based on work by David Glover, posted at http://www.davidglover.org/2010/09/using-the-fuji-finepix-real-3d-w3-camera-on-a-mac-or-linuxunix.html
# This script requires exiftool and ImageMagick.

FULLNAME="$1"
FILENAME="$(basename $FULLNAME)"
DIRNAME="$(dirname $FULLNAME)"
BASENAME="${FILENAME%.*}"

# Create output directories
mkdir -p "$DIRNAME"/stereoscopic-rl/
mkdir -p "$DIRNAME"/stereoscopic-mpo/
mkdir -p "$DIRNAME"/stereoscopic-anaglyph/
mkdir -p "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/
mkdir -p "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/

# Create separate left and right images
exiftool -trailer:all= "$FULLNAME" -o "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left.jpg
exiftool "$FULLNAME" -mpimage2 -b > "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right.jpg

# Move the MPO file to its new home
mv "$FULLNAME" "$DIRNAME"/stereoscopic-mpo/

# Determine parallax value and create cropped images for stereo generation
# 36 is only appropriate for 4:3 or 3:2 images
parallax=$(exiftool -b -Parallax "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right.jpg)
parallax=$(echo "$parallax"*36+0.5 | bc | cut -d . -f 1)

# The above pipeline can't deal with a parallax of zero
# In theory, this fix doesn't cover values between zero and -1
# TODO improve the calculation
if [ ! $parallax ]; then
    parallax=0
fi

echo $parallax

if [ $parallax -ge 0 ]; then
    convert "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left.jpg -crop +"$parallax"+0 "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left-cropped.jpg
    convert "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right.jpg -crop -"$parallax"+0 "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right-cropped.jpg
else
    convert "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left.jpg -crop -"$((-1*$parallax))"+0 "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left-cropped.jpg
    convert "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right.jpg -crop +"$((-1*$parallax))"+0 "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right-cropped.jpg
fi

# Create stereoscopic images for cross-eye (right-left) and anaglyph (red-cyan) viewing
convert "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right-cropped.jpg "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left-cropped.jpg +append "$DIRNAME"/stereoscopic-rl/"$BASENAME"-stereoscopic-rl.jpg

composite -stereo 0 "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right-cropped.jpg "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left-cropped.jpg "$DIRNAME"/stereoscopic-anaglyph/"$BASENAME"-stereoscopic-anaglyph.jpg

# Clean up separated parallax-corrected images
rm "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-l/"$BASENAME"-left-cropped.jpg
rm "$DIRNAME"/monoscopic-r/"$BASENAME"-right-cropped.jpg

exit 0
```

Comment: sorry... Error 404

Comment: I've added the script I wrote in 2010 to the answer; hopefully it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using bbe (http://bbe-.sourceforge.net/) which is a sed like program for binary files:

In order to extract the first JPEG use:

```
bbe -b '/\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE1/:' -e 'D 2' -o first_jpeg mpo_file
```

And for the second one:

```
bbe -b '/\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE1/:' -e 'D 1' -o second_jpeg mpo_file
```

Note that this will not work if the JPEG's magic number occurs somewhere else in the MPO file.

Comment: Thanks for bringing bbe to my attention! By the way, your Sourceforge link is broken, and bbe.sf.net is a different project.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Bart is on to your biggest problem.. If that binary sequence repeats during the process, you will get partial JPEGs.

I did a quick test by concatenating some JPEGs and then extracting them with awk (please note that the magic number in my files ended in 0xE0 and not 0xE1):

```
   # for i in *.jpg ; do cat $i ; done > test.mpo 
   # awk 'BEGIN {RS="\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0"; FILENUM=-1} {FILENUM++; if (FILENUM == 0) {next}; FILENAME="image0"FILENUM".jpg"; printf "%s",RS$0 > FILENAME;}' test.mpo  
   # file image0*.jpg
    image01.jpg:  JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
    image010.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
    image011.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

This seemed to work ok for me, but the above mentioned issues are still unhandled and very real.

Comment: I guess 0xE1 in the magic number indicates that it's the second image in the sequence and you never have more than 2 images.  Adjust as needed. =)

Comment: I'm not sure about that, because I also see 0xE1 at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer check because awk is available on every Unix system (and it reminds me that I need to learn more about it :). My shell script is currently doing some rudimentary checks for an image03.jpg or lack of image02.jpg and aborting, which helps to handle the magic number problem. I could also do some checking for EXIF headers. Unfortunately, I'm only aware of one program that can read these files natively -- the Fujifilm Windows app -- although Wikipedia claims that Digikam supports MPO. Will have to look at their source, and my camera's documentation. For now, this is good.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Examples says that 0xFF 0xD8 is the beginning of the JPEG magic number, so it stands to reason that what follows it is up to the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think a very simple home brew approach will be your best bet. The code for doing this would be very small, depending on all the special cases of your binary file format.

1. Use `mmap` to get a convenient view of your file in memory.
2. Start scanning, and save the byte-offset in a variable, say `start`.
3. Scan until you reach your delimiter, saving the ending offset, in say `end`.
4. Create a new file
5. Memory-map the new file
6. Copy the byte-range from `start` to `end` into the new file.
7. Close the new file and start scanning again.

Answer (score 0):

FFE1 is not part of the some jpeg "magic number", it's the APP1 marker. And it's not guaranteed to come right after the SOI marker FFD8. Also, you should be careful that some jpeg images embed a thumbnail jpeg in an EXIF block. That will most likely also contain an APP1 marker.